# Define a density matrix in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to define the density matrix for the maximally entangled state of a two qudit system in Wolfram Mathematica. The matrix is in the form of

[image]

Here's the code:

```
ket[i_, d_] := 
 Module[{n = 1, TempKet = {}}, 
  While[n - 1 != d, 
   If[n == i, TempKet = Append[TempKet, {1}], 
    TempKet = Append[TempKet, {0}]]; n++]; TempKet]
bra[i_, d_] := Transpose[ket[i, d]]
Rho[d_] := 
 Sum[Sum[TensorProduct[Dot[ket[i, d], bra[j, d]], 
     Dot[ket[i, d], bra[j, d]]], {i, d}], {j, d}]*1/d
```

However, the error message "Tag Integer in 1[d_] is Protected." popped out. I have no idea what "1[d_]" is.

Comment: You probably tried to define this functions when `Rho` had a value of 1. Clear its value and try again.